# ошибка TypeError string indices must be integers

Tags: python

```
while True:
    i = 0
    thisCode = input()
    print('Reading..', thisCode)
    for i in list(thisCode):
        if thisCode[i] == 3:
            print("Hello world!")
```

7357
Reading.. 7357
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\79788\Desktop\Python\lava\main.py", line 6, in 
if thisCode[i] == 3:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Так в i у вас элемент списка, а не индекс

Comment: Можете пожалуйста уточнить что у вас не получилось и что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Вы внесли в `thisCode` строку, а затем через `list(thisCode)` преобразовали её в список символов. Далее, Вы пытаетесь обратиться к очередному символу, беря значение из списка символов и подставляя его в индекс массива, хотя ***индексами могут быть только неотрицательные целые числа.***

Замените в условии `thisCode[i]` на `i`, и тогда программа будет проверять символ с тройкой (забегая вперёд, скажу, что лучше и `3` заменить на `'3'` — символы жеж).